# Как настроить компилятор Delphi 7 на максимальную производительность?

Tags: delphi, компилятор

Я знаю, что компилятор может быть настроен либо на оптимизацию по производительности, либо по размеру файла.. Но не знаю как..

Если не прав - поправте меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть [старинная статья](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/perform.htm) по оптимизации производительности в Delphi. В том числе внимание уделено и настройкам компилятора.

Comment: Спасибо, жаль что подобных вещей нет на русском..

Comment: Ну посмотреть как галочки расставить в опциях компилятора можно ведь. на крайняк - всегда есть [машинный перевод](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ru&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.drbob42.com%2Fdelphi%2Fperform.htm) этой статьи )

Comment: А что это за утилитка там такая "delphi 32-bits efficiency"?

Comment: Это не утилита, а тестовая программа, на которой автор объясняет те или иные нюансы.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо ещё раз за статью!

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, в Delphi можно в настройках включитьотключить отладочные символы (что будет влиять на размер файла тоже), включитьвыключить оптимизацию кода и есть еще некоторые параметры. Суть оптимизации заключается в оптимизации ассемблерного кода (удаление неиспользуемых переменных и прочей лабуды))), фишка которая позволяет получить большой, но быстрый код или маленький и более медленный, теоретически должна быть, но явно в настройках IDE ее не видел.

Comment: Ну, вот всё это я слышал и читал об этом тоже.. Только вот КАК включить этот самый режим "большой и быстрый код"? На размер исполняемого файла мне всё равно. Мне нужно чтобы данные быстро обрабатывались.